# Is there any way to change response of auth:api , A laravel api_token

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I am creating API with [Default api-authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/api-authentication)

I am using laravel 6.x

Its run when i generate on user register and pass generated token with request.

But

1. when i pass a wrong token, Then it shows a Login page HTML, i want to show some custom **JSON** response instead of **HTML**
2. Also is there any way to check that passed token is same with passed user id or not. Because user can pass different user id with token.

My `api` route file as below

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->post('/listUser', 'ApiController@listUser');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have manage my points as below

**For Point 1**

1. when i pass a wrong token, Then it shows a Login page HTML, i want to show some custom **JSON** response instead of **HTML**

I made change in `App/Exceptions/handler.php`

Modify `render function` as below

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
        if ($request->is('api/*')) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Not Found'], 404);
        }
        //return response()->view('404', [], 404);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

It workrs  well because i have an `api` based routes

My api route look likes

```
// Request with Authentication v1

Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'namespace' => 'Api\v1', 'middleware' => ['api','auth:api'] ], function () {

  Route::post('/myProfile', 'ApiController@myProfile');

});

// Request without Authentication v1
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1', 'namespace' => 'Api\v1', 'middleware' => 'api'], function () {
  Route::post('/register', 'ApiController@register');

});
```

**For Point 2**

2. Also is there any way to check that passed token is same with passed user id or not. Because user can pass different user id with token.

For that i have created a function `checkValidations` in `ApiController` and check `user id` is associated with particular `token` or not as below:

In that function i check in way that

1. Check for all `validation` passed from called method
2. Match `token` associated with `user id` then return `success`
3. else `return` invalid token response

**Function Code**

```
public function checkValidations($required = [], $request = [])
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $required);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
         $this->response[] = array(
                'status' => 'false',
                'response_msg' => implode(",",$validator->messages()->all()),
            );
         return array('response' => $this->response);
    } else if(isset($request['api_token']) && auth('api')->user()->id == 
         $request['id']) {
        return 'success';
    } else {
        $this->response[] = array(
                'status' => 'false',
                'response_msg' => 'Invalid token',
            );
         return array('response' => $this->response);
    }
}
```

**And call that `checkValidations` from any function and can reuse it as**

```
public function myProfile(Request $request)
{
    $validation = [
           'id' => 'bail|required|exists:users',
           'api_token' => 'bail|required|min:60|max:60'
     ];
    if( $this->checkValidations($validation, $request) == 'success'){
            $this->response[] = array(
                    'status' => 'true',
                    'response_msg' => 'Success',
                            'data' => auth('api')->user()
                );
    }

    return array('response' => $this->response);

}
```

May be there is many other best way to manage that points, but i didn't found, so i manage in above ways.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can configure a custom response in the `Authenticate` middleware. e.g.

   ```
   public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
       {
           if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
               if ($guard === 'api') {
                   return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
               } else {
                   return redirect()->guest('login');
               }
           }
           return $next($request);
       }
   ```
2. You can do this by extending the `TokenGuard`, with your custom logic. Or you can create a new Middleware, which asserts that user authenticated by API matches the passed user ID.

Comment: in my `Authenticate` middleware just one function => `protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
    }`

Comment: and if i paste your function in that middleware it gives an error.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra you need to provide more specifics on the error

Comment: it gives error => `ErrorException: Declaration of App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = NULL) should be compatible with Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards) in file E:\xampp\htdocs\larablog\app\Http\Middleware\Authenticate.php on line 9`

Answer (score 0):

I just verified the kind of exception if is related with authentication and then the URL( as API guard use '/api' just verify it) and fire the response.

```
if($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException){
            if($request->is('api/*')){
                return response()->json([
                    'success' => false,
                    'message' => 'User not logged'
                ]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the below change in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`.

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Not Authorized'], 404);
    }

    return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
}
```

Add `use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException` in the document. Also, do not forget to add `X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest` to your request header. (Or Headers in postman)

`return redirect()->guest(route('login'));` is to redirect you to login page when you are not using the APIs.